# error: passing ‘const Integer’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Integer Integer::pow(int)’ discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

I have `Integer` class that is supposed to simulate an integer mod n. Thus, it has constructors like:

```
Integer::Integer(int x)
    : m(x), n(0)
{

}

Integer::Integer(int x, int y)
    : n(y), m(x)
{
    // if this->n greater than 1
    if (this->n > 1)
    {
        // mod this->m by this->n
        this->m %= this->n;
        // if this->m is negative
        if (this->m < 0)
        {
            // add this->n to it 
            this->m += this->n;
        }
    }
}
```

There is also `Integer::inverse()`, `Integer::pow(int)`, which are needed for completeness of this question:

```
Integer Integer::inverse()
{
    // Extended Euclidean Algorithm
    int t = 0,
        r = this->n,
        newT = 1,
        newR = this->m;     
    while (newR != 0)
    {
        int quotient = r / newR,
            tCopy = t,
            rCopy = r,
            newTCopy = newT,
            newRCopy = newR;
        t = newT;
        newT = tCopy - quotient * newTCopy;
        r = newR;
        newR = rCopy - quotient * newRCopy;
    }
    if (r > 1)
    {
        throw Integer(-1);
    }
    if (t < 0) t = t + this->n;
    return Integer(t, this->n);
}

Integer Integer::squared()
{
    return Integer(this->m * this->m, this->n);
}

Integer Integer::pow(int x)
{
    // if x less than 0, return this->inverse().pow(-x)
    if (x < 0)  return this->inverse().pow(-x);
    // if x is 0, return Integer(1)
    if (x == 0) return Integer(1, this->n);
    // if x is 1, return *this
    if (x == 1) return *this;
    // if x is 2, return this->squared()
    if (x == 2) return this->squared();
    // if x greater than 2
    if (x > 2)
    {
        // if x is even 
        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            // return this->pow(x/2).squared()
            return this->pow(x/2).squared();
        }
        // return this->pow(x/2).squared() * (*this)
        return this->pow(x/2).squared() * (*this);
    }
}
```

Problem I'm having is when I go to implement `Integer::isQuadraticResidue() const`:

```
bool Integer::isQuadraticResidue() const
{
    // if this->n is zero
    if (this->n == 0)
    {
        // this doesn't belong to Integers mod anything. check for perfect square instead
        double baseSquareRoot = std::sqrt((double)this->m);
        return (baseSquareRoot == (double)((int)baseSquareRoot));
    }
    // this is quadratic residue iff this->pow((this->n + 1) / 2) == Integer(1, this->n)
    return (this->pow((n + 1) / 2).m == 1);
}
```

I get following error: `error: passing ‘const Integer’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Integer Integer::pow(int)’ discards qualifiers`. I think it has everything to do with the `const` on the end. What do?

EDIT: Class header file looks something like:

```
#ifndef INTEGER_H
#define INTEGER_H

#include <iostream>

class Integer
{
    public:
        Integer(int);
        Integer(int, int);
        // functions
        Integer inverse();
        Integer squared();
        Integer pow(int);
        bool isQuadraticResidue() const;
        Integer sqrt();
    private:
        int m, n;

};

#endif
```

Comment: There is no need to mutate this, so should I just `const_cast<bool>` the return value? Am I doing the XY-problem here?

Comment: To answer that question, no.

Comment: can you add class interface?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I solved it by removing `const` modifier from function. Now, I would like to know why, if at all, I should not have it `const`.

Comment: I'd like to take a look on your class declaration

Comment: is pow returns an object of other class?

Comment: Nope, it returns `Integer` and is member of `Integer`.

Comment: if you;d like add class declaration

Comment: As an off topic comment, there is zero point in documenting your code with things like `// if x less than 0, return this->inverse().pow(-x)`  ... in fact it detracts from the code, other readers will begin to ignore comments as they're just spurious noise and may miss actual *useful* comments ..

Comment: Basically, you'd want `const` there to indicate that the function doesn't change the instance's logical state.  This is a very strict promise, and any function that makes it isn't allowed to take any actions that risk breaking it (which includes calling member functions which _don't_ make that promise).  If every function is `const`, except the ones that are specifically intended to change state, then the class is overall safer, because it won't change where you don't expect it to.

Comment: A general rule of thumb, use const references and remove the const or references if you have a reason to.  I think if you were to do Integer(const int&), and so on, you should be good.  Your "this" pointer has turned into a const, essentially, when you add const to the method declaration. So, you need to make sure everything else in your program respects that, which means you can't pass "this" to something that could modify it.  So, add lots more consts and remove as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with `const` correctness, where a `const` function is trying to call a non-`const` function.

```
// ...

bool Integer::isQuadraticResidue() const;
Integer Integer::pow(int x);

// ....
```

In this situation, `this` is an `Integer*` in `pow()`, and a `const Integer*` in `isQuadraticResidue()`; this means that `pow()` can call `isQuadraticResidue()`, because it's legal to add CV-qualifiers, but not the other way around (because `pow()` would have to accept `this` as a non-qualified `Integer*`, losing the `const` qualifier).

This is unallowed, because allowing it would mean that `isQuadraticResidue()` breaks its guarantee that it won't modify the instance, whether directly or indirectly.  While it itself doesn't change state, it assumes that `pow()` *does* change state, because `pow()` isn't also `const` (and thus doesn't promise not to change state).  Due to this, `isQuadraticResidue()` is unable to call `pow()`, because doing so would risk breaking its guarantee.

---

Considering that, there are two solutions for this issue.

1. Remove `const` from `isQuadraticResidue()`.  This would naively solve the problem, but isn't recommended, because then you wouldn't be able to reap the benefits of `const` correctness.
2. Make all member functions that don't modify `Integer`'s logical state `const`, as well.  This will require a bit more effort, but is overall safer.  As they can then be called on a `const Integer` just as well as they can on an `Integer`, you will then be able to pass your instances around as `const` whenever they don't need to be modified, giving you a greater degree of safety.

   ```
   Integer Integer::inverse() const;
   Integer Integer::squared() const;
   Integer Integer::pow()     const;
   ```

   This will need to be changed both in the functions' prototypes, and in their definitions.

Comment: Here's the answer. ^^.  Well written.

Answer (score 0):

the problem maybe you declared pow's this as non-const and trying to invoke it from isQuadraticResidue()const so in c++ it is not allowed to do so:

const this calls only member function whose this is const
you should either make pow's this const and as I guess it is bad idea becuase maybe you want to change some member data in it.

otherwise make isQuadraticResidue's this non-const

```
Integer pow(int x);        // this is non const
bool isQuadraticResidue(); // this is not const
```

now everything is ok. as you can see after adding class declaration we get the error where!